# Is it possible to change a string parameter with a For Loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm not a programmer, neither studying something related to it, but just someone who wants to run a code to make my work life easier.

I need to open 50 tabs. Opening one by one takes so much time because when I click the open button, it shows me the new tab opened and then I have to go back to the original page to open the next one and so on.
After a weekend of doing some research, I found that Google Chrome has a "Console" that can be modified to make a webpage work as you want.

The code that runs to open a tab in this webpage is the following. I've run this code in the console and surprisingly it works:

```
if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){
jsfcljs(document.getElementById('ngFindListForm'), {'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:0:j_id178':'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:1:j_id178'},'_blank');}
```

And to open the next tab is:

```
if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){
jsfcljs(document.getElementById('ngFindListForm'),{'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:1:j_id178':'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:1:j_id178'},'_blank');}
```

As you see, the "only" part of code that changes is the number between colons **(0 and 1)**.
So, according to my basic-high school-programming skills, I think I can change those number with a For Loop from 0 to 49 (50 tabs). I've tried that like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
param = 'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:' + i +':j_id178';}
```

And then using this **param** something like this:

```
if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){
jsfcljs(document.getElementById('ngFindListForm'),{param:'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:1:j_id178'},'_blank');}
```

But it's not working. It just makes to open the same page I'm on in a new tab.
Maybe the logic I have figured out how to make this work is totally wrong, but this is why I came here to ask you.

Thanks

Comment: First, make sure that the call to `jsfcljs` is also in the for loop. Otherwise, you'll change the parameter 50 times and use it once. Also, try printing the resulting arguments with `console.log(param);` before the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your code inside `foreach` and use `[param]` (ES6)

```
var form = document.getElementById('ngFindListForm');
if (typeof jsfcljs == 'function') {
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var param = 'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:' + i + ':j_id178';

    jsfcljs(form, {
      [param]: 'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:1:j_id178'
    }, '_blank');
  }
}
```

OR

```
var form = document.getElementById('ngFindListForm');
if (typeof jsfcljs == 'function') {
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj['ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:' + i + ':j_id178'] = 'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:1:j_id178';

    jsfcljs(form, obj, '_blank');
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `[param]` will create a list. I don't know why you think that would work.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Its an `ES6` way of using variables as object keys. [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it, the easiest would be to use an object and set the string

```js
function jsfcljs(e, o, t) {
  console.log(o);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var obj = {}
  obj['ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:' + i + ':j_id178'] = 'ngFindListForm:tblDataTable:' + i + ':j_id178'
  jsfcljs(document.getElementById('ngFindListForm'), obj, '_blank');
}
```

```html
<div id="ngFindListForm"></div>
```